# Need to find number of locations for each product purchased?

Tags: mysql, sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have 2 tables (customer, transaction).

```
customer
id  name location
1    samuel AZ
2    mithun  CA
3    Robert  NY
etc..


transaction
id   customer_id  product_id
1     1            12000
2     1             12222
3     3             15000
etc.
```

There are different products and different locations

By these columns I need to find number of locations one particular product was purchased?

I tried using joins.

My code was

```
select c.id, c.location, t.product_id
from customer c join transaction t
on (c.id = t.cid);
```

I was able to join two tables but I need count the number of transactions by tid.

Answer (score 0):

Try grouping them - This provides the number of locations a particular product was purchased. This will includes duplicate entries for the locations but will answer your Number of transactions bit

```
select t.product_id, count(c.location)
from customer c join transaction t
on (c.id = t.cid)
group by 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

To find "number of different locations per product id" simply use `GROUP BY` according to the `product_id`

```
 select t.product_id, count(distinct c.location)
 from transaction t
 join customer c on (c.id = t.id)
 group by product_id
```

use `distinct` in `count` to avoid counting the same location twice.